# Updating and Existing OLEDB Connection using VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am tying to update an existing connection in a spreadsheet with a modifiable script.

Basically, I want the use to be able to put in a list of Account References, push a button, and Excel spits out the SQL output where those Account References match what we have one system.

I've managed to collate all of the script into one cell (F1 on my Workings tab), so that's all fine, and I've added the preliminary connection (and called it "CustomerContactDetails").

I have enabled the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library as well.

My VBA script is:

```
Sub UpdateScript()

Dim Script As String

SQLScript = Worksheets("Workings").Range("F1").Value

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CustomerContactDetails").OLEDBConnection.ConnectionString = SQLScript
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CustomerContactDetails").Refresh

End Sub
```

I get the error on the fourth line down (ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CustomerContactDetails").OLEDBConnection.ConnectionString = SQLScript):

**Run-time error '9';
Subscript out of range**

Does anyone know how to help with this please? It feels like I'm not that far way, and I'm not trying to do anything too complicated. I just can't seem to get it to work!

Comment: You don't mention which line is giving you the error, but you either don't have a worksheet "Workings" in the active workbook, or there's no connection named "CustomerContactDetails" in that workbook.

Comment: I've updated the question now, thanks for pointing that out.
I have definitely named the things correctly, there is a connection called that and a sheet called that. I have checked, and the variable is 'populating' (not sure of the correct term) as the script.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this and see what output you get

```vb
Sub UpdateScript()

    Dim Script As String
    Dim conn as WorkbookConnection

    For Each conn in ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        Debug.Print conn.Name
        If conn.Name = "CustomerContactDetails" Then
            SQLScript = Worksheets("Workings").Range("F1").Value
            conn.OLEDBConnection.ConnectionString = SQLScript
            conn.OLEDBConnection.Refresh
        End If 
    Next conn
End Sub
```

EDIT: looks like what you have is a `WorkbookQuery`
I created one (to an Oracle DB) and you can access and revise it something like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim q As WorkbookQuery, lo As ListObject
    
    Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Query1")
    
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Count
    Set q = ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Query1")
    
    Debug.Print q.Formula
        
    'revise query
    q.Formula = "let" & vbCrLf & _
       " Source = Oracle.Database(""BLAH"", [HierarchicalNavigation=true," & _
       "Query=""select * from table1""])" & _
       vbCrLf & "in" & vbCrLf & "Source"
    
    lo.Refresh 'I got a popup "do you want to run this?" here...
    
End Sub
```

Note it's nearly always useful to try recording a macro while creating the type of object you're having trouble modifying - that will point you to the syntax you need.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! I added it as a 'Query Table' which I've not seen before. Also, the name is "Query - CustomerContactDetails" (because it's a query not a connection?).

I've tried changing the conn variable to a QueryTable instead of WorkbookConnection, but get "Object variable or With block variable not set".

I tried to simply change the connection name to 'Query - CustomerContactDetails' but that got "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Is this something I can do with a Query instead of a Connection? I'm using Excel version 2107 if that helps. Thank you.

Comment: Exactly how did you create the query?

Comment: Data -> Get Data -> From Database -> From SQL Server Database -> input the script and click Ok etc.